# AngularJS click a cell on the table which will direct to another webpage

Tags: angularjs, html, button, angularjs-ng-click

I have an angular table, which represents real-time data coming from the server. If i click on on a row (or any cell in the row), I need to redirect the page to another html page.And I don't know how to do this. Can anyone give me an example?

Comment: Can you share any code you have worked on so far to try to achieve this?

Comment: `ng-click` and `$location` are two things you will.

Comment: `<a href="myotherpage.html">I'm this thing they call a link</a>`

Answer (score 0):

```
    <table border="1" class="table">

        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <th ng-repeat="(key,value) in payment"> {{key}} </th>
            </tr>
            <tr>

                <td ng-repeat="(key,value) in payment"> 
                    <button> 
                        {{value}} 
                    </button> 
                </td>

            </tr>
        </tbody>
```

I haven't created any function in my .js file. The code above only adds button on my values, but does not do anything else. I tried several ways, couldn't solve it. What do I need to do in order to achieve this: click the values, which will take you to another website. It is so simple as you see..

Comment: If this is the correct anwer, please mark it as such when you can.

Comment: add a ng-click at your button